# Как сделать чтобы на iOS работал :active у элементов?

Tags: html, css

Как сделать чтобы на мобилах (iOS, Safari) работал `:active` у элементов? Когда на компе кликаешь по элементу, становится `:active` на секунду, меняется цвет фона. Но когда пальцем на смартфоне тыкаешь — эффекта нет.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tvyfgjwb/

вот как пример

Comment: поправка. это не работает только на IOS

Answer (score -2):

Простое добавление этой строки `$('body *').on('touchstart', function (){});` делает :active рабочим на IOS Iphone Safari

Comment: Чтобы дополнить свой вопрос, просим вас воспользоваться опцией редактирования. Кнопку «Опубликовать ответ» следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/430910)

Comment: это и есть ответ, читай внимательнее. решение найдено.

Comment: Чего заминусовали, это и в самом деле рабочий ответ (хоть и сомнительный по производительности, лучше бы селектор сделать не столь широким)

Comment: @andreymal, возможно потому что в оригинале был капсом и с десятком восклицательных знаков.

Comment: @insolor во-первых, вместо минуса есть правка (которую вы сделали), а во-вторых, третий минус появился уже потом, странно

Comment: @andreymal, это уже вопрос не ко мне, а к минусующим.